# How can I fork a PPA

Tags: ppa

There is this PPA with lots of modified packages, but some are not of the version I need. How can I fork that PPA, and update only the packages I need?

Comment: Do you need newer versions of the software or do you need packages for an other Ubuntu release?

Comment: Actually, I am trying to fix a build error in the original PPA...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. **Create your own PPA on Launchpad**
2. **Goto the source PPA**
3. **Click on <kbd>View package details</kbd>**

   [image]
4. **Click on <kbd>Copy packages</kbd>**

   [image]
5. **Select your packages to copy, select the target PPA (your PPA) and the Ubuntu release**

   [image]
6. **Go to your PPA and wait for the rebuild**

   [image]
7. **Add your PPA to your system**